# Retrieve all items from DynamoDB using query?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to retrieve all items in a dynamodb table using a query. Below is my code:

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from time import sleep

c    = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(aws_access_key_id="XXX",aws_secret_access_key="XXX",region_name="us-west-2")

tab  = Table("rip.irc",connection=c)

x    = tab.query()

for i in x:
    print i
    sleep(1)
```

However, I recieve the following error:

```
ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
{'message': 'Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only', '__type': 'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}
```

The code I have is pretty straightforward and out of the boto dynamodb2 docs, so I am not sure why I am getting the above error. Any insights would be appreciated (new to this and a bit lost). Thanks

EDIT: I have both an hash key and a range key. I am able to query by specific hash keys. For example,

```
x = tab.query(hash__eq="2014-01-20 05:06:29")
```

How can I retrieve all items though?

Answer (score 64):

Ahh ok, figured it out. If anyone needs:

You can't use the query method on a table without specifying a specific hash key. The method to use instead is scan. So if I replace:

```
x    = tab.query()
```

with

```
x    = tab.scan()
```

I get all the items in my table.

Comment: This is not a solution, you are not gonna use scan for your app logic, it is very costly! You should rethink your indexes and use query or get_item !

Comment: scan is a reasonable solution for small tables. Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html

Comment: .scan() also does not automatically return all elements in a table due to pagination of the table, there is a 1mB limit to each response. After that, you will need to make subsequent scans with the "LastEvaluatedKey" attribute

Answer (score 13):

I'm on groovy but it's gonna drop you a hint. Error :

```
{'message': 'Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only'}
```

is telling you that your key condition can be length 1 -> **hashKey only**, or length 2 -> **hashKey + rangeKey**. All what's in a query on a top of keys will provoke this error.
The reason of this error is: you are trying to run **search** query but using **key condition** query. You have to add separate **filterCondition** to perform your query.
 My code

```
    String keyQuery = " hashKey = :hashKey and rangeKey between :start and :end "
    queryRequest.setKeyConditionExpression(keyQuery)// define key query
    String filterExpression = " yourParam = :yourParam "
    queryRequest.setFilterExpression(filterExpression)// define filter expression
    queryRequest.setExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
    queryRequest.setSelect('ALL_ATTRIBUTES')
    QueryResult queryResult = client.query(queryRequest)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Вадим, you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 13):

.scan() does not automatically return all elements of a table due to pagination of the table. There is a 1Mb max response limit [Dynamodb Max response limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

Here is a recursive implementation of the boto3 scan:

```
import boto3
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb')


def scanRecursive(tableName, **kwargs):
        """
        NOTE: Anytime you are filtering by a specific equivalency attribute such as id, name 
        or date equal to ... etc., you should consider using a query not scan

        kwargs are any parameters you want to pass to the scan operation
        """
        dbTable = dynamo.Table(tableName)
        response = dbTable.scan(**kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('Select')=="COUNT":
            return response.get('Count')
        data = response.get('Items')
        while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
            response = kwargs.get('table').scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'], **kwargs)
            data.extend(response['Items'])
        return data
```

Comment: Why not just use the pre-built [scan paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Scan)?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error when I was misusing `KeyConditionExpression` instead of `FilterExpression` when querying a dynamodb table.

`KeyConditionExpression` should only be used with partition key or sort key values.
`FilterExpression` should be used when you want filter your results even more.

However do note, using `FilterExpression` uses the same reads as it would without, because it performs the query based on the `keyConditionExpression`. It then removes items from the results based on your `FilterExpression`.

**Source**
[Working with Queries](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the other answers and comments. If all records are needed use `scan` instead of `query` (it requires key filters).

ref: [scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/table/scan.html), [paginator('scan')](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/paginator/Scan.html)

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer

session = boto3.Session()
client = session.client("dynamodb")

paginator = client.get_paginator('scan')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    TableName=table_name
)

data = []
for page in response_iterator:
    for item in page['Items']:
        # convert to python types
        deserializer = TypeDeserializer()
        python_data = {k: deserializer.deserialize(v) for k, v in item.items()}

        # append to list
        data.append(python_data['data'])
```

Answer (score -5):

This is how I do a query if someone still needs a solution:

```
def method_name(a, b)
    results = self.query(
      key_condition_expression: '#T = :t',
      filter_expression: 'contains(#S, :s)',
      expression_attribute_names: {
        '#T' => 'your_table_field_name',
        '#S' => 'your_table_field_name'
      },
      expression_attribute_values: {
        ':t' => a,
        ':s' => b
      }
    )
    results
  end
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.