# how to specify multiple conditions on DynamoDB Query Operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-dynamodb

how to specify multiple conditions on DynamoDB Query Operation?

```
var params = {
            TableName: "liveTraining",
            KeyConditionExpression: "#ContentId = :contentId and #CompanyId = :companyId and #Status=:status",
            ExpressionAttributeNames:{
                  "#ContentId": "ContentId",
                  "#CompanyId": "CompanyId",
                  "#Status": "Status"
                },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":contentId": contentId,
                ":companyId": companyId,
                ":status": 'Active'
                }
        };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          dynamoDB.query(params, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('Unable to fetch data', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            } else {
              console.log('fetched data', response);
            }
          })
        });
```

when I specified more than two conditions using AND operator I got an error:

```
Unable to fetch data {
  "message": "Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2019-04-12T06:53:34.766Z",
  "requestId": "MOE9FDN6I62NLROVPPTDMS5V2JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 29.17802723976769
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515765/retrieve-all-items-from-dynamodb-using-query

Comment: The key condition expression can only contain conditions on the hash key and sort key. Any other conditions must go in a filter expression.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify at max **two conditions** for a query operation *within the `KeyConditionExpression`*. Any further conditions need to applied through a filter using the `FilterExpression`.

Every query operation requires at least a Partition Key. You can optionally specify a Sort Key.

The `KeyConditionExpression` allows for the following:

1. an equals operator on the Partition Key
2. an accepted operator / operation on the Sort Key

Here's the [list of comparison operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) you can use for Sort Keys.

Any other additional attributes must be specified in a `FilterExpression`. Keep in mind, you will be charged the RCUs for everything picked up by the `KeyConditionExpresion`, despite only receiving what has not been filtered by the `FilterExpression`.

From the same link as above, regarding consumption and filters on queries:

> A filter expression is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned. Therefore, a Query consumes the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present.

[AWS DynamoDB Query docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on query mechanics sums it up nicely:

> You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single value for that attribute ... Use the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter to provide a specific value for the partition key ... You can optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a sort key value and a comparison operator in `KeyConditionExpression`. To further refine the Query results, you can optionally provide a `FilterExpression`.

Comment: Your response was informative, but I think the meat of this question is "how to specify multiple conditions" since the docs are vague on the syntax.

Comment: The error occurred when the asker tried to use more than two conditions, which is what I addressed. I will add additional information around specifying more than one condition.